# Sapui5 list with max rows

Tags: javascript, list, sapui5

I have a sap.m.List with 50 items and I need to just show 4.
My idea is to show 4 rows and a Scrollbar but I don't know how to develop it.

How can I solve this? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Pablo, did my solution help you?

Comment: This solve my problem but in other way, I mean: doing this, the list show a button with the number of rows showed and the total rows number, example: 4/10, and when I click this button, the list show more rows. I just want to show a scroll bar without this button. There is any way?

Comment: You can program your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please use property [setGrowingThreshold](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#setGrowingThreshold) to 4. Also you need to set property [setGrowing](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#setGrowing) to true before using property setGrowingThreshold. This will do job for you.

EDITED 13:40 270317:

I edited simple [example](http://jsbin.com/nedevusufa/1/edit?html,js,output) with 5 items. It grows +1.

```
var list = new sap.m.List({
   headerText:"Names",                
});
list.setGrowing(true);
list.setGrowingThreshold(1);
```